# Need to append text to beginning of input field.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following code, I send the text to a server, but I want the username appended to the beginning of the field. Any ideas on how this can be done? A prototype solution is below.

```
function chatSend(){
    console.log(input.value)
    input.value = name+":"+input.value; // Something like this 

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",           
       data: JSON.stringify({text: $('input').val()}), 
       success:function(message){


       }
  });
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you have defined `name` correctly, and `input` as the input field in question, this should work just fine, what is the problem?

Comment: in the ajax request data, are you sure you mean `$('input').val()` not `$(input).val()` or `$('#id').val()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did something not work? I wrote it like this and this works fine:

```
chatSend($('.inp'));

function chatSend(input){
    console.log($(input).val())
    $(input).val("username" + ":" +$(input).val()); 
    console.log($(input).val())
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5DL9s/)